# How to render multiple shapes and objects in OpenGL3.2+?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am following this guide http://open.gl/ to learn how to program using modern opengl. I am stuck at one thing. Earlier with older opengl Api, I used to create different functions for drawing different types of shapes. Like drawRect(), drawCircle(), etc. All I needed to do was to use glVertex3f() in different combinations inside glBegin() and glEnd().

But in OpenGl3.2+, even to draw a rectangle, we have to write hell lot of code. I understand that it gives you more control over rendering, but I am confused at what to do when you are rendering multiple stuff like drawing rectangles, circles, etc together. Do I need to write all that code multiple times including shaders or I can reuse the code.

I have implemented this code http://open.gl/content/code/c2_triangle_elements.txt 
This example draws a rectangle, but what If I wanted to draw a triangle along with this rectangle, then how do I do it.

Comment: I think you need to understand fully how shaders and buffers ect work in a more in-depth fashion.

With a vertex buffer bound you can map the vertices and change them like that or use a model matrix and a uniform in the shader to move the shape and draw it twice with different model matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse most of the code. All the shaders can be loaded once and the reused by calling `glUseProgram`. As for all the buffers you can create them once and then reuse them as many times as you want.

You might want to create some classes like `ShaderClass` and `ShapeClass`.

A base shader class will usually have 2 or 3 parameters like `program`, `vertexShader` and `fragmentShader` (all being some IDs). When you extend them also add all the uniforms and attributes from the shaders so you can later use them to modify your drawing (change the colour for instance).

A `ShapeClass` will usually contain vertex buffer ID (and optional index buffer ID) and number of vertices to draw.

So in the end when wanting do draw some shape you only use a shader you already created and compiled, bind and set the vertex data from your shape buffer and call the draw.

Comment: hmm...I am getting it...Thanks :)
I am little bit confused about Vertex Array Object. Do I to create it once in the starting or for every ShaderClass.
Also do I have to call glVertexAttribPointer() every time after linking and using a program or just once.

Comment: VAO has nothing to do with shaders at all. You may use the same VAO with multiple shaders. You DO need to set all the data the shader needs after (and only after) you call glUseProgram, including the vertex pointer. You do not link the shader twice unless you are combining vertex and fragment shaders (you may have only 1 vertex shader and 2 fragment shaders and then share them), but again this has nothing to do with VAO as after you relink the shaders you will need to call glUseProgram and then rebind the attributes' and uniforms' data.

Comment: Also note you will probably have multiple glVertexAttribPointer calls after you use the program if you draw different shapes. Each time you want do draw a different shape (triangle, square) you can use a different VAO in which case you bind a different pointer but also bind a different buffer.

Comment: I tried implementing all this in a class. But's its not working. Here is the code http://pastebin.com/2fEMgae6

Comment: I have no idea why you packed the VAO into same class but never mind that. First you need to call Use() before you call Attribute(). Second I'm not too sure your shaders will compile this way. In glShaderSource try removing the reference to string pointer (remove the &) or rather define your Init as Init(const GLchar **vertShaderSource... By the way, do you have any more info on the issue besides "its not working"?

Comment: I Packed VAO into same class, because I thought If create multiple objects of it, I don't have to set attributes again after every glUseProgram, instead just bind the VAO when using that program.
Since, I am newbie, I can be wrong :P 

The whole program worked when it was into a single main() function. Also, the vertex Shader, fragment Shader and program are giving me no error. They show status result as 1

I have also tried calling Use() before attribute, but it still does not work

Comment: Still, you seem to have multiple errors in your code. Try going through it again. For instance in Attribute you bind the wrong buffer. You call glBindVertexArray(vao) instead of glBindVertexArray(vbo).

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I will write again from scratch, keeping it as simple and straight forward as I can.

Do you know of some resource that provide information on how to use modern openGL with OOP

Comment: I do not. You might get some source code from somewhere but this is something everyone might want to do on his own. It seems a lot of code when you first look at it but when you break it down into a few classes you see it is not. You need to understand what part of the code is needed to load some object and what code to use it, then you can keep it at minimum and the usability is great. I suggest you to drop me an email if you want to continue the discussion (you should find it on my profile).

Comment: I guess your email, is private, because I am unable to see it.

Comment: maticoblaksm@gmail.com